# Different GrayScales between System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb and PdfSharp.Drawing.XColor.FromArgb

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, colors, pdfsharp

I am generating a pdf using PdfSharp library.
One part of the pdf is the conversion from a Canvas (Canva's background set to White), the second is made with PdfSharp.
The problem I meet is depending in what generates the Brushes, I have a different result :

[image]

On the picture, I drew 5 different colors, the big rectangle has been drawn with XColor(PdfSharp library). Then the figure has been drawn inside a Canvas.

Here are the codes I use :

```
1 : 128,80,80,80
2 : 128,120,120,120
3 : 128,160,160,160
4 : 128,200,200,200
5 : 128,240,240,240
```

I made the test removing transparency (Color.A = 255), and all works perfectly, but as I want to get a transparency, couldn't get expected result. I tried to add a white background on PDF just to check, and nothing changes. Of course I coud just remove transparency, but couldn't explain myself why such behaviour?

Comment: Where are the PDFsharp samples coming from? Screenshots? Made with Adobe Reader? The display profile used by the PDF viewer may change the results.

Comment: @IlikedtheoldStackOverflow I made a screenshot from my web explorer (my default PDF viewer), what do you call "display profile"? Just if it could answer, the screenshot is all in a same page, do you think this would help to put the full screenshot?

Comment: If the PDF file is created in RGB mode (not CMYK mode) then PDFsharp should just add the colour values you specify to the PDF file. The colours rendered on the screen depend on the PDF viewer you use. You may get different results when you try different viewers (Adobe Reaber, Chrome, Foxit, ...).

Comment: @IlikedtheoldStackOverflow ok, I think you gave me an idea of the reason (just edited to show image), this is a legend. The difference is the details (on top) are generated in a Canvas, that is then converted to .png, and added inside .pdf. The boxes (bottom) are generated with PdfSharp.DrawRectangle(). The only reason I see is when Canvas is transformed into png, the result is a little different. I checked with Paint.net, for "1", on the bottom Color code is (167,167,167) (correct), and on detail on top code is (123,123,123), as if transparency was not made correctly (or gray background).